# VBA / Internet Explorer / Javascript: How to open a javascript window from same internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation, childwindow

I am working on intranet. Using **VBA** I have to close some date from a list.

- I have selected the dates. Then clicked on a link to close (not button) which triggers a javascript.

**Selected all dates:**

`html.getElementsByName("selectall")(0).Click`

**Clicked on the link to close date.**

`html.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop`

**Part of javascript**

```
{
        //alert(xxx)
        document.first.deletepids.value = xxx
        window.open('closeallocation.asp?hotelid='+hotelid+'&roomtype='+roomtype+'&allocxid='+allocxid,'','toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=330,top=50,left=80')
        //window.open('closeallocation.asp?deletepids='+xxx+'&hotelid='+hotelid+'&allocxid='+allocxid)
    }
    else
    {
        if(confirm("Room(s) already having bookings for required dates.Do you wish to continue ?"))
        {
            document.first.deletepids.value = xxx
            window.open('closeallocation.asp?hotelid='+hotelid+'&roomtype='+roomtype+'&allocxid='+allocxid,'','toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=330,top=50,left=80')
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

- it opens a new window.

How do I either open the javascript window in the same window using VBA or when it opens in a new window  how do get elements or set value or click on the element of the new window?

I have tried to use shell window to search for all the opened window with title and locationurl but I didnt find that particular window for some reason.

```
Dim ow As ShellWindows
Dim fw As Variant
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Set ow = New ShellWindows

    For Each fw In CreateObject("Shell.application").Windows

        'On Error GoTo ErrorMsg
        If fw = "Internet Explorer" Then
            If InStr(fw.LocationURL, "displayhotelallocsummary.asp") <> 0 Then
            Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next fw

Set ie = fw
Set html = ie.document
```

Please advise.

Comment: I really don't mean to be rude, but you should seriously consider upgrading everything you know about web development. This looks a lot like what I did around the year 1999, and it felt bad then, too. Is this new software, or did you inherit it from someone who started making it about 10-15 years ago? By redoing this with modern methods, you will save your customer/employer a lot of money, and yourself a lot of stress.

Comment: Hi Andres. I am not offended at all. I fully understand your concern. You are not the first person who have this idea about my code. But the Javascript was written by thirdparty and I am just trying to get the data to excel. Company does not want to spend more money one hiring and expert programmer. So I am learning and working at the same time. I am happy that I am learning.

Sounds like you must be a very good programmer. Do you think there is a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I have a solution for you.

The following function allows you to activate the window you want so that you can analyze its HTML code.

1. Do your code and then a new webpage will open
2. Call this function `ie = ActivateWindow(path)` and put the path of your new page as an argument
3. The function will go through all the open windows from your computer and activate the one containing this path

   ```
   Function ActivateWindow (sLocation As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

   Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
   Dim window As Object, Good_one As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

   For Each window In objShellWindows
    On Error Resume Next ' We add this so that if there's an issue in the procedure to get the typeName of the window, we just skip it since it s not the window we re looking for anyway
       If TypeName(window.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
           If UCase(window.document.Location) = UCase(sLocation) Then
               Set Good_one  = window
               Exit For
           End If
       End If
   Next

   Set ActivateWindow= Good_one 

   End Function
   ```

Comment: Hi Seb, when I click on the CLOSE link with the mouse pointer it opens a pop up window. but when I use vba code to click on the link internet explorer pop and ask to ALLOW ONCE for the pop up window.

How do I use vba code to click on the link to click like mouse or select the link and sendkey enter so that I can apply your code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your answer. The code I posted is valid when the window you want to work on ALREADY exists, but in not the active one. As long as it exists, even if Internet opens a Pop up window, it should work

Comment: The problem here is IE is stopping me from opening the pop up window. it is asking for permission when I click with Code. but if I click with mouse it opens the pop up window. How do I solve it? they are not same problem but one is stopping another.

Comment: Ok so do this :  `Dim objShell As Object`
    `Dim IE_count As Integer`
   `Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count`
    `MsgBox IE_count ' number of internet tabs and folder open (visible or not)` . Put this line before you click on the button which opens the pop up window and check which number you get. Then put it after the pop up window + the window you are interested in open and let me know which numbers you get

Answer (score 0):

`1. How do I open the javascript window in the same window?`

```
window.open('closeallocation.asp?hotelid=2&roomtype=3','_self','toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=330,top=50,left=80')
```

The `_self` parameter indicates that the URL will replace the current page

`2. Or when it opens in a new window how do get elements or set value or click on the element of the new window?`

You can pass parameters by querystring

```
var myWindow = window.open('closeallocation.asp?hotelid=2&roomtype=3','','toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=330,top=50,left=80');
```

In the example above you're passing two parameters (`hotelid=2 and roomtype=3`)

Comment: When I click on the CLOSE link with the mouse pointer it opens a pop up window. but when I use vba code to click on the link internet explorer pop and ask to ALLOW ONCE for the pop up window. How do I use vba code to click on the link to click like mouse or select the link and sendkey enter?

Comment: I think you get the popup, because VBA needs special permissions configured in the browser... You should use javascript instead... Something like this in javascript should work `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();`

Comment: hi Bastos, where should I write this code? within my vba code?

Comment: No, it's javascript, VBA won't compile that... You'll have to run it in a javascript code block...

Comment: But I can not run it in javascript. that webpage where the javascript runs I do not have any access to it. its a could software.